# Bash find- is showing the files but returning no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a bash script I cannot get working. I am a dead set beginner in bash this is actually the first script I've ever used. I'm trying to get omxplayer to play a list of files in a directory.  When the script runs I get feedback showing the file then the error that there is no such file or directory. Please help me?

```
#!/bin/sh
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/ -name "*.mp3" -exec PLAY={} \;; omxplayer "$PLAY";
```

This is the echo:

```
find: `PLAY=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Dance.mp3': No such file or directory
find: `PLAY=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Whitemary.mp3': No such file or directory
find: `PLAY=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Limo.mp3': No such file or directory
find: `PLAY=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Silo.mp3': No such file or directory
File "" not found.
```

Comment: Neither `find` nor any program it runs via `-exec` can set a variable to use in the current shell.

Comment: `find /path/ -name "*.mp3" -exec omxplayer {} \;` ?  Or even, `for f in /path/*mp3; do omxplayer "$f"; done` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `-exec foo` part means run the command `foo` for each path found.
In your case, `-exec PATH={}`, the `{}` part is replaced with the path name, ending up with something like `-exec PATH=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Dance.mp3`, and so then `find` tries to run the command `PATH=/media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/Dance.mp3` which fails because there isn't actually any such program to execute.

`xargs` is the usual way to do what you're trying to do, as described in another comment already.
You could also do:

```
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/ -name \*.mp3 |
while read f; do
   omxplayer "$f"
done
```

Comment: This solution is akin to [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you're going to pipe filenames from `find`, use `-print0` and `xargs -0`. Don't do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3 -name \*.mp3 -exec omxplayer {} \;
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' mp3
do
   omxplayer "$mp3"
done < <(find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3 -name \*.mp3 -print0)
```

or

```
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3 -name \*.mp3 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 omxplayer
```

You can omit the `-n1` if the `omxplayer` could handle multiple filenames. In such case the 1st could be written as:

```
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3 -name \*.mp3 -exec omxplayer {} +
```

but the simplest probably will be

```
#shopt -s globstar #the default is on
for mp3 in /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/{,**/}*.mp3
do
    omxplayer "$mp3"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I stand corrected, but won't delete the answer as you can also learn from the mistakes of others. See comment and rather use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42884601/2626627) :)

So please don't do it like this, as this is a typical "happy path" solution - meaning: it works if you know what you're doing and you know your paths (e.g. that they don't contain spaces). I keep forgetting that many people don't know yet that spaces in paths are evil.

Just use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to pass what you found to your player like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /media/pi/88DC-E668/MP3/ -name "*.mp3" | xargs omxplayer
```

Comment: Spaces or newlines will break this. As with waxrat's answer, this solution is akin to [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you're going to pipe filenames from `find`, use `-print0` with `xargs -0`. Don't do it this way.